# Manipulate function

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to generate this simple graph using the Manipulate function

```
f[x_] := a x + b x^2;
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

However, Mathematica doesn't return any graph! If instead of the above, I use now

```
Manipulate[Plot[a x + b x^2, {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

I can get what I wanted. Any thoughs on why the manipulate doesn't work with functions?
Thanks!

Comment: This is covered in the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for `Manipulate`. See example after `Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you must pass `a` and `b` to the function. Try `f[3]` with your current definition and you get `3a + 9b` which cannot be plotted. When using `SetDelayed` (`:=`), it cannot see that there is an `a` and `b` inside the function so it does not know where to assign the values. Instead, try this:

```
f[x_, a_, b_] := a x + b x^2
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, a, b], {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Image of Manipulate]